# Уменшения трафика с Firebase на пользователя

Tags: база-данных, ios, firebase, swift3, coredata

Сейчас сделано так: чтение данных с **Firebase Realtime Database (FDB)** пишу их в **CoreData(CD)**. Есть кнопка принудительного обновления (очищаю полностью **CD** и перезаписываю данные с **FDB** через `observeSingleEvent`)

Функция загрузки очистки и записи данных в **CoreData**:

```
func loadCDDAta(completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    NetworkCheckingClass.isConnectedToNetwork(){

        isConnected in

        if isConnected == true {

            if Reachability.sharedInstance.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {

                self.ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in


                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary


                    if snapshot.value != nil {

                        self.deleteRecords()

                        if let f = value?["Place"] as? [String:AnyObject] {

                            CoreDataManager.instance.saveCDDict(f)
                        } else if let f = value?["Place"] as? [AnyObject] {

                            CoreDataManager.instance.saveCDArray(f)

                        }

                        completionHandler(true)

                    } else {

                        completionHandler(false)

                    }

                }) { (error) in
                    completionHandler(false)
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

            } else {

                completionHandler(false)
                print("NO Connect")

            }

            print("Connect OK")

        } else {

            completionHandler(false)
            print("NO Connect")
        }
    }

}



func deleteRecords() -> Void {
    let moc = CoreDataManager.instance.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "DictPlace")

    let result = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
    let resultData = result as! [DictPlace]

    for object in resultData {
        moc.delete(object)

    }

    do {

        try moc.save()
        print("saved!")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch {

    }

}
```

То есть, если Json с **Firebase** весит 20Mb то тянет все 20Mb.

Нужно: по нажатии кнопки смотреть изменение данных в **FDB** и если изменились, то дописать в **CD** только те которые были изменены или новые (не снося всё остальное). А если ничего не менялось - то не трогать ничего.

Json с только обновленными данными с **Firebase** весит максимум 100-200Kb 
+ меньше время загрузки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, хранить также в файрбейзе хеши по данным. То есть сделать отдельную ветку и туда писать только уникальные хеши. Их стянуть будет быстрее, затем сверить актуальный ли хеш в локальной базе и тогда тянуть или не тянуть данные, за которые отвечает хеш.